# C++ update structure offset

Tags: c++, struct

when i trying make function to set meshes, then i got error E0137. getMeshes works well.
When i trying to do somethink like

```
RpMesh* a = header->GetMeshes();
a = newMeshes;
```

this too not working.

```
struct RpMeshHeader
{
    unsigned int   flags;
    unsigned short numMeshes;
    unsigned short serialNum;
    unsigned int   totalIndicesInMesh;
    unsigned int   firstMeshOffset;
    RpMesh *getMeshes(void) { return (RpMesh*)(this + 1); }
    void setMeshes(RpMesh* newMesh)
    {
        (RpMesh*)(this + 1)= newMesh;
    }
    bool isValidMeshId(int meshId)
    {
        return (meshId != NULL && numMeshes >= meshId);
    }
}
```

Whole file
https://github.com/CrosRoad95/mtasa-blue/blob/f740b0d7410f33ff323cad25bf897725ad44d7d3/Client/sdk/game/RenderWare.h

Comment: What is error E0137? Which line does it occur on? Copy the *exact* error message and show the exact code that causes it

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to achieve via `(RpMesh*)(this + 1)= newMesh;`?This will pretty much always invoke *undefined behavior*

Comment: line (RpMesh*)(this + 1)= newMesh;
The C ++ expression must be a modifiable l-value

Comment: i want to update (this + 1)

Comment: You still haven't provided the necessary information (such as the error message). Also what exactly do you think `this + 1` is?

Comment: this + 1 is not what you think it is

Comment: you are updating the pointer instead of what it is pointing at! Add a * before the expression and also a * before newMesh if you want to copy.

Comment: yes, i know that `this + 1` is `RpMesh*`

Comment: No, you don’ know.

Comment: `meshId != NULL`? This is some really odd looking comparison to `0`...

Comment: ` void setMeshes(RpMesh newMesh { * (RpMesh*)(this + 1)= newMesh;}`
seems to work

Comment: "seems to work" does not mean it works. Undefined Behaviours often seem to *work* until you encounter an error that's unexplainable to you, because you assumed something *was supposed to work*

Comment: what is the best way to update this?

Comment: Probably redesign your entire structure relations in order to not invoke underfined behaviour. I'd start with using STL instead of manual memory management

Comment: the redesign is gone

Answer (score 0):

The error here is quite clear:

```
void setMeshes(RpMesh* newMesh)
{
    (RpMesh*)(this + 1)= newMesh;
}
```

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

the following is not an `lvalue` and so you cannot assign to it.

```
(RpMesh*)(this + 1)
```

The github you linked shows the setMeshes as the following

```
void setMeshes(RpMesh* newMeshes)
{
    RpMesh* meshes = (RpMesh*)(this + 1);
    meshes = newMeshes;
}
```

which is fine in terms of syntax. First you create a pointer `meshes` to which you assign the address of `(this+1)` (if `this` was an array, `this+1` would point to the next element in the array) but with a cast!

You cast this hypothetical next element in this array of `RpMeashHeader` to `RpMesh` with a C-style cast (which afaik will default to a `reinterpret_cast` in this case see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used) for more information)

But has this memory every been allocated? This seems unsafe.